# Wrapping a C++ class and accumulating return values for its member methods

Tags: c++, templates, stl, std, perfect-forwarding

I have a serializer class that serializes data through sequenced method calls:

```
enum class Status {
    INVALID_KEY = -2,
    OUT_OF_SPACE = -1,
    SUCCESS = 0
};

bool IsError(Status s) {
    return s != Status::SUCCESS;
}

class Serializer {
public:
    void Init();
    Status BeginStruct();
    Status EncodeKeyValue(int key, std::string value);
    Status EndStruct();
};
```

When I sequence those methods, it makes for some cumbersome writing:

```
    f.Init();

    status = f.BeginStruct();
    if (IsError(status)) {
        return -1;
    }

    status = f.EncodeKeyValue(2, "test-value");
    if (IsError(status)) {
        return -1;
    }

    status = f.EndStruct();
    if (IsError(status)) {
        return -1;
    }
```

How can I achieve something like the following:

```
    wrappedf.BeginStruct()
        .EncodeKeyValue(2, "test-value")
    .EndStruct();
    
    if (IsError(wrappedf.GetAccumulatedStatus()) {
        return -1;
    }
```

Constraints: I would like to avoid modifying Serializer's declaration or definition if possible.

Comment: You have to modify `Serializer` because its methods do not support chaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `Serializer` methods to return `*this` and then throw exceptions on error.  There's no way to do it without modifying your `Serializer` class.

Example:

```
class Serializer {
public:
    void Init();

    Serializer &BeginStruct() {
        [do_work];
        if (error)
            throw std::runtime_error ("something went wrong");
        return *this;
    }

    Serializer &EncodeKeyValue(int key, std::string value) {
        [do_work];
        if (error)
            throw std::runtime_error ("something went wrong");
        return *this;
    }

    Serializer &EndStruct() {
        [do_work];
        if (error)
            throw std::runtime_error ("something went wrong");
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And then you can do:

```
try
{
    wrappedf.BeginStruct()
        .EncodeKeyValue(2, "test-value")
    .EndStruct();
}
catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
{
    [handle error];
}
```

You might also consider following the example of `std::ostream` and overloading `operator<<`.